# Adding a new field to an existing index from CSV using logstash

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have an index in ElasticSearch with the following fields

```
EmpId | Name | Age | Title
```

It contains some data , I need to add other fields like

```
Address | City | MobileNumber
```

These extra columns are exist in a CSV file

```
EmpId| Address | City | MobileNumber
```

below is logstash.conf

```
input {
    file {
        path => "D:/data.csv"
        start_position =>"beginning"
        sincedb_path =>"index/test1"
    }
}

filter {
    csv {
    separator => ","
    columns => ["EmpId","Address","City","MobileNumber"]
    }
}

output {
     elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
        index => "myindex"
        document_id => "%{EmpId}" 
    }
stdout {}
}
```

Now when I run this file , old fields are removed and I can only see the new columns
"EmpId","Address","City","MobileNumber"

How can I add a new fields but keep old fields as well ?

Answer (score 1):

Add these two lines to your `elasticsearch` output section:

```rb
    action => "update"
    doc_as_upsert => true
```

So the whole output block would be:

```rb
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
        index => "myindex"
        document_id => "%{EmpId}"
        action => "update"
        doc_as_upsert => true
    }
}
```

Further reading:

- [Elasticsearch Update API docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#doc_as_upsert)
- [Logstash ES Output's "action" setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-action) (see also the `doc_as_upsert` setting, obviously)

[Edit: complete rewrite after discovering this totally works. Mea culpa]